# materialdesigninxaml - TextBox validation text overlapping with another textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to make simple login form card and inside i have TextBox for Username and PasswordBox for password. I have added Validation Rule (as shown in demo app for materialdesigninxaml), but the problem is that then validation message overlaps with the PasswordBox.

[image]

I have tried adding bottom padding for all TextBox elements but it did not help. Only solution that i can think of is to add top padding to bottom elements but i do not like that solution because it messes up with my layout.

User Control:

```xml
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16" MaxWidth="500">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox x:Name="UsernameTextBox" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Username"  MaxLength="20">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Username" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <rules:NotEmptyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Password" MaxLength="10" />
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
```

ValidationRule:

```cs
public class NotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? "").ToString())
                ? new ValidationResult(false, "Field is required.")
                : ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }
```

Essentially what i want is to have space reserved for these validation messages instead of them being shown over elements below the TextBox with minimal modification of code (i don't want to manually add padding/margins to every single element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a global `Style` in your `App.xaml` where you give all `TextBoxes` some bottom margin:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,15" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this was exactly kind of solution i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

the validation message placement can be changed when the popup option is choosen.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="materialDesign:ValidationAssist.UsePopup" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="materialDesign:ValidationAssist.PopupPlacement" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```